# Sharing torrents between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, xubuntu, deluge

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu and Win7. The torrents are downloaded to the same folder, but is there a way to easily share the magnet links between the two deludge installations? This would be easy with the old torrent files, but now a days only magnet links are used.

Example of what I want: I'm in ubuntu and start a torrent download. Before it's finished I switch to windows and open deludge which will continue the download.

As it is now I have to manually add the link to my windows deludge and vice versa, so my question is; is there any smoother way to handle this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the `AutoAdd` plugin (Deluge >= 1.3.4) which supports parsing a text file with a .magnet extension containing either a single or list of multiple magnet uris.